# Revert an apfs volume to the state of an earlier snapshot

Tags: macos, apfs

Recently, I have a problem with slow login. I copied the system to another Mac and is trying different things to solve the problem. To be clear of what exact method works, I plan to restore to an earlier snapshot every time. Reading the output of `apfs.util` in `/system/library/Filesystems/apfs.fs/Contents/resources`, it seems like I should be able to do that:

```
Usage: apfs.util [[-p][-k] /dev/diskXsYsZ]|[-s /dev/diskXsY]|[-R SNAPSHOT][-M dir][-S dir][-O path]
   -p : probe for volume name
   -k : get volume UUID
   -s : set volume UUID(s) and container UUID to new random values
   -R SNAPSHOT : set the volume to revert to the snapshot named by SNAPSHOT on next mount.
```

So I tried, but I get error code 254 with no error message:

```
apfs.util /dev/rdisk4s1 -R com.bombich.ccc.safetynet.CEFF3106-2AF7-4789-8A50-B36921496E27.2020-10-31-104558
root@Joys-MacBook-Pro /s/l/F/a/C/resources [254]#
```

I tried doing this while the drive is mounted and not mounted. I tried using the XID instead. I tried another snapshot and it didn't work. How can I make it work? This is not documented in the man page and I can't find any information online. Because this is not a Time Machine snapshot, it does not show up in "restore from backup" in recovery system.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue on macOS Ventura 13.3.1 -- ever end up figuring this out?